# How can I translate a refreshControl's title in a localized storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, localization

I have localization in my iOS app. On the storyboard it works for all elements, but not for the refresh control's title.

I have tried:

```
"Rqf-Hb-7hc.title" = "Update";
"Rqf-Hb-7hc.normalTitle" = "Update";
"Rqf-Hb-7hc.text" = "Update";
"Rqf-Hb-7hc.attributedTitle" = "Update";
```

...without any luck.

Does anyone know how can I translate the Refresh Control in my MainStoryboard.strings file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's an attributed string, you should do the localization from code.

**Objective-C**

```
NSString *title = NSLocalizedString(@"refresh control title", @"comment");

NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14],
                             NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor]};

[refreshControl setAttributedTitle:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:title attributes:attributes]];
```

**Swift**

```
let title = NSLocalizedString("refresh control title", comment: "comment")

let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14),
                                                 .foregroundColor: UIColor.black]

refreshControl?.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: title, attributes: attributes)
```